# Comparing argv and L"test" Not Working

Tags: c++

So here I have

```
if(argv[0] == L"test") {
    cout << "it is test";
}
else {
    cout << "Nope."
}
```

And it always displays "Nope." I don't know what I'm doing wrong... I've tried using different ways but they all end up the same way.

Comment: Is the parameter being passed actually a wide character string?  If it is, then maybe the environment that you are using to compile has made provisions to specially process command arguments given to `main` that are wide strings (for example Visual Studio has, I believe, `TCHAR**` for the argument array).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie doesnt matter arv[0] == any sort of string isnt going to work. some form of strcmp is needed

Comment: Yes, I know.  Just wondering if the runtime actually is capable of sending wide string arguments or not.

Comment: @BoPersson this question touches on `wchar_t` issues whereas the other one doesn't, so I wonder if it should be reopened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wcscmp().

You're main function has to pass a wide character for argv[0] like so:

```
int main(int argc, wchar_t*argv[])
```

then you can do:

```
 if (wcscmp(argv[0], L"test"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great.

Answer (score 3):

A more C++ like solution would be:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    if (argv[0] == wstring(L"test")) {
        cout << "it is test";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Nope.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not a fan personally - `wcscmp` exists and works correctly; constructing two `wstring` objects just wastes time and memory

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) as `argv` is an array of `char*`.

Your code compares the pointers instead of the string content.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated when comparing `wchar_t` strings (`L"test"`) to `char` strings. Some combination of `mbstowcs()` and `wcscmp()` would be in order.